# Dynamic Topic Name in Community Cloud using LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, html, lightning-community, developer

I have a LWC which shows the sub topics of the community, which is **'Hard Coded'** for the reference, ideally I want it dynamic.

You can see in the image, the component in red are provided by Salesforce, but this is not user friendly, where as in purple you can see my own LWC, which is how I aim for.

How can I make this dynamic?

1. Where Accordion Section would show me - Related Topic Name
2. When section is opened, then it shows - Related Article list
3. Related Article List is a hyperlink to the actual article.

.html

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="FAQs / General Information">
        <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
            <lightning-button
                label="Expand All"
                onclick={expandAll}
                class="slds-m-around_medium">
            </lightning-button>
            <lightning-button
                label="Collapse All"
                onclick={collapseAll}
                class="slds-m-around_medium">
            </lightning-button>
        </div>
        <lightning-accordion allow-multiple-sections-open class="slds-m-around_medium" active-section-name={activeSections}>
            <lightning-accordion-section name="A" label="Payments & Deliveries FAQ">
                <p>
                    Related Article 1 - for Payment & Deliveries   <br/>                      
                    Related Article 2- for Payment & Deliveries   <br/>
                    ... <br/>
                    
                </p>


            </lightning-accordion-section>
            <lightning-accordion-section name="B" label="Notes On End Customer Support">
                <p>
                    Testing 4<br/>
                    Testing 5<br/>
                    Testing 6<br/>

                </p>
            </lightning-accordion-section>
            <lightning-accordion-section name="C" label="Contact The Seller">
                <p>
                    Testing 7<br/>
                    Testing 8<br/>
                    Testing 9<br/>

                </p>
            </lightning-accordion-section>
        </lightning-accordion>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

.js

```
    import { LightningElement, api} from 'lwc';

export default class CustomAccordionLWC extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;

    
    
    activeSections = [ 'A', 'B', 'C' ];

    expandAll() {

        this.activeSections = [ 'A', 'B', 'C' ];

    }

    collapseAll() {

        this.activeSections = [];

    }

}
```

.js-meta.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>57.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__Tab</target> 
        <target>lightningCommunity__Page</target> 
        <target>lightningCommunity__Default</target> 
        <target>lightningCommunity__Page_Layout</target> 
        <target>lightningCommunity__Theme_Layout</target> 
        </targets>
    
        <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightningCommunity__Default">
            <property
                name="recordId"
                type="String"
                label="Record Id"
                description="Pass the page's record id to the component variable"
                default="{!recordId}" />


                
    </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>
```

[image]